# How to Loop through multiple Col values in a dataframe to get count

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a list of tables let say x,y,z and each table is having some cols for example test,test1,test2,test3 for table x. just like we have cols like rem,rem1,rem2 for table y. Similarly is the case for table z. Now the requirement is that we have to loop through each col in a table and have to get row count based on below scenario's.

- If test is not NULL and all other are NULL(test1,test2,test3) then it will be one count.

Now we have to loop through each table and then find cols like test* then match the above condition then marked that row as one 1 count if it satisfy above condition.

I'm pretty new to scala but i thought of the below approach.

```
for each $tablename{
{
Val df = sql("select * from $tablename ")
val coldf = df.select(df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("test")).map(df(_)) : _*)
val df_filtered = coldf.map(eachrow ->df.filter(s$"eachrow".isNull))

}
}
}
```

It is not working for me and not getting any idea where to put the count variable.if someone can help on this i will really appreciate.
Im using spark 2 with scala.

## Code update

below is the code for generating the table list and table-col mapping list.

```
val table_names = sql("SELECT t1.Table_Name ,t1.col_name FROM table_list t1 LEFT JOIN db_list t2 ON t2.tableName == t1.Table_Name WHERE t2.tableName IS NOT NULL ").toDF("tabname", "colname")

//List of all tables in the db as list of df

val dfList = table_names.select("tabname").map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList
val dfTableList = dfList.map(spark.table)



 //Mapping each table with keycol
val tabColPairList = table_names.rdd.map( r => (r(0).toString, r(1).toString)).collect
val dfColMap = tabColPairList.map{ case (t, c) => (spark.table(t), c) }.toMap
```

After this i'm using the below methods..

```
def createCount(row: Row, keyCol: String, checkCols: Seq[String]): Int = {

  if (row.isNullAt(row.fieldIndex(keyCol))) 0 else {
    val nonNulls = checkCols.map(row.fieldIndex(_)).foldLeft( 0 )(
      (acc, i) => if (row.isNullAt(i)) acc else acc + 1
    )
    if (nonNulls == 0) 1 else 0
  }
}

val dfCountList = dfTableList.map{ df =>
df.cols
  val keyCol = dfColMap(df)
  //println(keyCol)
  val colPattern = s"$keyCol\\d+".r
  val checkCols = df.columns.map( c => c match {
    case colPattern() => Some(c)
    case _ => None
  } ).flatten

  val rddWithCount = df.rdd.map{ case r: Row =>
    Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq ++ Seq(createCount(r, keyCol, checkCols)))
  }
  spark.createDataFrame(rddWithCount, df.schema.add("count", IntegerType))
```

its giving me below error:

```
createCount: (row: org.apache.spark.sql.Row, keyCol: String, checkCols: Seq[String])Int
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: [id: string, projid: string ... 40 more fields]
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
  at $$$$cfae60361b5eed1a149235c6e9b59b24$$$$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:121)
  at $$$$cfae60361b5eed1a149235c6e9b59b24$$$$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:120)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
  ... 78 elided
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement, I would suggest taking advantage of RDD's functionality and use a `Row-based` method that creates your `count` for each Row per DataFrame:

```
val dfX = Seq(
  ("a", "ma", "a1", "a2", "a3"),
  ("b", "mb", null, null, null),
  ("null", "mc", "c1", null, "c3")
).toDF("xx", "mm", "xx1", "xx2", "xx3")

val dfY = Seq(
  ("nd", "d", "d1", null),
  ("ne", "e", "e1", "e2"),
  ("nf", "f", null, null)
).toDF("nn", "yy", "yy1", "yy2")

val dfZ = Seq(
  ("g", null, "g1", "g2", "qg"),
  ("h", "ph", null, null, null),
  ("i", "pi", null, null, "qi")
).toDF("zz", "pp", "zz1", "zz2", "qq")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType

val dfList = List(dfX, dfY, dfZ)
val dfColMap = Map(dfX -> "xx", dfY -> "yy", dfZ -> "zz")

def createCount(row: Row, keyCol: String, checkCols: Seq[String]): Int = {
  if (row.isNullAt(row.fieldIndex(keyCol))) 0 else {
    val nonNulls = checkCols.map(row.fieldIndex(_)).foldLeft( 0 )(
      (acc, i) => if (row.isNullAt(i)) acc else acc + 1
    )
    if (nonNulls == 0) 1 else 0
  }
}

val dfCountList = dfList.map{ df =>
  val keyCol = dfColMap(df)
  val colPattern = s"$keyCol\\d+".r
  val checkCols = df.columns.map( c => c match {
    case colPattern() => Some(c)
    case _ => None
  } ).flatten

  val rddWithCount = df.rdd.map{ case r: Row =>
    Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq ++ Seq(createCount(r, keyCol, checkCols)))
  }
  spark.createDataFrame(rddWithCount, df.schema.add("count", IntegerType))
}

dfCountList(0).show
// +----+---+----+----+----+-----+
// |  xx| mm| xx1| xx2| xx3|count|
// +----+---+----+----+----+-----+
// |   a| ma|  a1|  a2|  a3|    0|
// |   b| mb|null|null|null|    1|
// |null| mc|  c1|null|  c3|    0|
// +----+---+----+----+----+-----+

dfCountList(1).show
// +---+---+----+----+-----+
// | nn| yy| yy1| yy2|count|
// +---+---+----+----+-----+
// | nd|  d|  d1|null|    0|
// | ne|  e|  e1|  e2|    0|
// | nf|  f|null|null|    1|
// +---+---+----+----+-----+

dfCountList(2).show
// +---+----+----+----+----+-----+
// | zz|  pp| zz1| zz2|  qq|count|
// +---+----+----+----+----+-----+
// |  g|null|  g1|  g2|  qg|    0|
// |  h|  ph|null|null|null|    1|
// |  i|  pi|null|null|  qi|    1|
// +---+----+----+----+----+-----+
```

[UPDATE]

Note that the above solution works for any number of DataFrames as long as you have them in `dfList` and their corresponding key columns in `dfColMap`.

If you have a list of Hive tables instead, simply convert them into DataFrames using `spark.table()`, as below:

```
val tableList = List("tableX", "tableY", "tableZ")
val dfList = tableList.map(spark.table)
// dfList: List[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = List(...)
```

Now you still have to tell Spark what the key column for each table is.  Let's say you have the list in the same order as the table list's.  You can `zip` the list to create `dfColMap` and you'll have everything needed to apply the above solution:

```
val keyColList = List("xx", "yy", "zz")
val dfColMap = dfList.zip(keyColList).toMap
// dfColMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,String] = Map(...)
```

[UPDATE #2]

If you have the Hive table names and their corresponding key column names stored in a DataFrame, you can generate `dfColMap` as follows:

```
val dfTabColPair = Seq(
  ("tableX", "xx"),
  ("tableY", "yy"),
  ("tableZ", "zz")
).toDF("tabname", "colname")

val tabColPairList = dfTabColPair.rdd.map( r => (r(0).toString, r(1).toString)).
  collect
// tabColPairList: Array[(String, String)] = Array((tableX,xx), (tableY,yy), (tableZ,zz))

val dfColMap = tabColPairList.map{ case (t, c) => (spark.table(t), c) }.toMap
// dfColMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,String] = Map(...)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually in my case the cols are dynamic for ex in table x we can have cols which start with test and can be  test, test1, test2, test3, test4 but in table y we might have only rem, rem1, rem2. there are around 100 tables which i have to loop through and i have to select col dynamically as cols can vary acc to tables. Im sorry if my requirement was not clear.

Comment: @techjunkie, not sure I understand your requirement.  If you meant the number of columns in the tables are different, the provided solution already takes care of that (with `(1 - row.size).foldLeft` in the `createCount` method).  The ~100 tables can be placed in the final list of `List(dfX, ...)` for processing, hence shouldn't matter.

Comment: Or, did you mean given a table, the columns of interests are only a subset of the entire row?  In other words, say in tableX, the key column (i.e. test) may not be the first column and the columns to be null-checked (i.e. test1, test2, ...) are only part of the remaining columns?  If so, you'll need to provide criteria for picking those columns.  For example, is it always the case that if the key column name is `aaa`, the columns to be null-checked will be `aaa? (? = 1, 2, ...)`?

Comment: yes you got it right the cols we need to select from a table will be subset of all the cols. The criteria is for example for table x we should select only cols which starts with test or u can say Show cols like test*.
so this gives me (x-> test, test1, test2, test3, test4)
for table y it will be (y->rem, rem1, rem2) 
Yes there can be cols before test as well with other names
After fetching the required cols for a table then we have to match the condition that will be the col name we put for getting the cols that is test should not null and all the other cols should be NULL.

Comment: Rest all conditions should be count as zero. in the fetched list of required cols for a table the condition matching col for example test in case of x->test, test1, test2, test3 ... test will be the first col.

Comment: The answer has been revised to handle your latest described requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the update . in my case i have around 100 tables for which i cannot manually build the df for each table as you have build three DF. I tried something like

`val dfList = dfList.map{ df =>
    println(df)
    sql(s"select * from $df ")
    }`

 for creatin the list of df But its just storing the list the cols list for each table..

Comment: I've expanded the answer to address your table-to-DataFrame need.

Comment: Really Appreciate your Help. So i got the List for all the tables in db and its giving me the below.

`dfTableList: List[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = List([col1: string, col2: string ... 41 more f`


i can see  for every table in the dfTableList its showing  all the cols name.is it what expected.

Below is my code

`val dfList = table_names.select("Table_Name").map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList
val dfTableList = dfList.map(spark.table)
val keyColList = table_names.select("col_name").map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList
val dfColMap = dfTableList.zip(keyColList).toMap`

Comment: Yes, that's just Spark trying to show the content of the result list.  The important thing is that it interprets the result type `dfTableList: List[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]` correctly.  I would recommend that you start with a smaller list (say, a dozen or less) of tables for testing.

Comment: My dfColMap is not in same order as the dfList. I sorted the dfList by dfname but for dfColMap i tried sortByKey (Key here is tablename) but sortByKey is not working. Below is the code for dfColMap


   `//mapping tablename to keycols`
   `table_names = sql(selecting tablename and colname from a table)`
    `val tblRdd=table_names.rdd`
    `val dfColMap = tblRdd.map(row => `
    `(row(0),row(1).toString)).collectAsMap()`

as the tablename are not in the same ordering as dfList(list of tables as df) the dfColMap function say's - key not found error.

Comment: Please see my further expanded answer.  By design, `Map` is for key lookup and does not preserve order.  You only need to make sure the key-value elements in the Map are paired up correctly.  If you look at my sample code, the only place `dfColMap` is used is for looking up a dataframe key for the corresponding column value, hence how Scala orders the key-value elements in the Map is irrelevant.

Comment: I have changed the code and ran it. Its giving me the error which i have updated in the Q itself. The only thing which is coming to my mind is still its not able to find the key col in the dfcolmap .

Comment: As suggested previously, it'd be better you first test your code with just a handful of Hive tables and examine every step of the way to make sure all intermediary and final results are intact.  This would give you confidence that the code logic is sound so you can narrow down the problem space to corner cases as you move onto applying the same code to a big dataset.  On a separate note, what is the code line `df.cols` underneath `dfTableList.map{ df =>` for?